# Three.js reverse fisheye effect shader or WebVR distortion

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to distort video shot with a fisheye lens and applied to a hemisphere, for a 180 degree VR effect with one customised action camera. I've been trying using a Reverse Distortion Shader and now WebVR.

I see there is a 
[Distortion feature](https://github.com/borismus/webvr-polyfill/tree/master/src/distortion)
  in WebVR but I can't find any documentation for it

The lenses are 220 degrees so I've made the sphere 220 degrees.

The sphere is build as such

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 200,100,100, 0, 220 * (Math.PI / 180), 0, Math.PI);

var video = document.createElement( 'video' );
    video.loop = true;
    video.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
    video.preload = 'auto';
    video.muted = true;
    video.src = "http://video-processing.s3.amazonaws.com/example.MP4";
    video.play();

var texture = new THREE.VideoTexture( video );
    texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
    texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    texture.format = THREE.RGBFormat;
```

The distorted video is in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/bknill/pen/dpdaEm?editors=0010) with a shader I got from [here](http://www.decarpentier.nl/downloads/lensdistortion-webgl/lensdistortion-webgl.html)
[image]
I want to distort the video so it looks more like [this](http://beek.co/g370/s1924) 
[image]

I've tried a few methods, including adjusting the vertices etc. The above is trying to use a fisheye distortion shader and to try and reverse the effect.

I've played with the numbers including trying with negatives but can't get the effect I'm looking for.

Is this the right way about it? Does anyone know how to defish the view?

Comment: not quite an answer, but you should have a look at this: http://paulbourke.net/dome/fisheye/ and http://paulbourke.net/dome/fish2/ where the process is described in great detail.

Comment: Did you manage to get it working? I would love to do the same :)